# Nlog Parameter maxArchiveDays not supported on FileTarget

Tags: c#, nlog

Using NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.9.2
My config looks like this:

```
<targets>
    <target name="logFile" xsi:type="File" 
            fileName="logs/log-${shortdate}.txt" 
            layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
            archiveFileName="logs/archive/log-{#}.txt"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
            maxArchiveDays="1"/>
</targets>
```

I recieve the following error:

```
Exception when parsing .\Settings\NLog.config.
Parameter maxArchiveDays not supported on FileTarget
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check which version of Nlog you're using? The [doc](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archival-options) states it was "Introduced with NLog 4.7".

Comment: I'm using Nlog version 4.9.2.

Comment: Have you tried putting it not as the last parameters? Could be syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Yep, tried putting it in different places aswell. And to check Syntax, as soon as I remove `maxArchiveDays="1"` it works fine.

Comment: Strange one then, I guess you can try debugging nlog as described [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting#troubleshooting-steps).

Comment: Tried it out, this is what I get:

`2020-05-20 15:01:39.2844 Debug Setting 'FileTarget.maxArchiveDays' to '1'
2020-05-20 15:01:39.3319 Warn Error when setting '1' on attibute 'maxArchiveDays' Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Parameter maxArchiveDays not supported on FileTarget
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're using the [`NLog.Web.AspNetCore` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore).
This package has a dependency to

> NLog.Extensions.Logging (>= **1.6.2**)

which itself depends on

> NLog (>= **4.6.8** && < 5.0.0-beta01)

So when you add the package to a .NET Core 3.0 project, here's what you got:
[image]

As you can see, NLog version 4.6.8 is installed, which does not support this parameter indeed.

There is actually an [issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/562) on the package repo so I think the update to next version is planned.

In the meantime, adding the [NLog package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog) to the project solve the error.

> Install-Package NLog -Version 4.7.2

Comment: Thank so much! This was it!